# Freeswitch JWT Integration

Tags: python, lua, jwt, sip, freeswitch

I am trying to make an integration between a sip client and FS system. SIP Client sends a JWT token as a password during the authentication stage.

In order to authenticate a client, FS creates a directory entry with the password field and compares it to the password received from the client, in my case I need to override this behaviour by getting the "token" which appears as password, verifying it and returning the answer to FS about the result of the verification so it will know whether to accept or to reject the user.

I am not sure how to override this behaviour in FS without change of the source code. I would prefer to write a python or lua plugins to deal with that.

Many thanks,

Comment: could you elaborate the complete workflow in more detail? You can generate the FS directory entries on the fly by mean of mod_xml_curl, and that would contain the dynamic password field. But that needs testing. Another approach would be to use Kamailio as a SIP registrar instead of FreeSWITCH.

Comment: Hi, we have a client using PJSIP library and inside AuthCredInfo struct (data field) we pass JWT token to the FS. We need to find a way to verify the token instead of password comparison which is done using standard procedure. Basically I need to execute a script on the username / password and return true or false to the FS so it will know if user is allowed or not.

Comment: I still think that kamailio would fit better as a SIP registrar in this case. If there's a budget, I'll be glad to help in designing and building a POC for this. You can easily find my contact if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the following solution should be used.

In order to allow FS work with JWT for authentication it is necessary to send JWT inside the custom header from the user agent to the FS. Also it is important to put some known password to the user agent.

When UA is connecting to the FS and when building dynamically the directory using lua script (xml-handler-script, xml-handler-bindings) it is possible to validate the JWT and provide the right directory entry for the user simply by reading the custom-header fields.

If JWT was valid then correct password (known one) will be used to allow FS to proceed with that, otherwise - another non valid password will be provided and FS will drop the connection.

Hope that helps to somebody,

Comment: looks valid, if FS doesn't have any other ways to know the token. I thought the JWT token issuer and FS are able to access the same back-end and know about valid tokens

Comment: Thanks Stanislav. FS is not aware about the auth server and it has to validate the customer based on the token which is signed and has an expiration date. It makes the procedure much faster because it does not require a db lookup for that user.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parameters in FreeSWITCH:

1. accept-blind-auth: accept any authentication without actually checking (not a good feature for most people)

   ```
   <param name="accept-blind-auth" value="true"/>
   ```
2. auth-calls: users in the directory can have "auth-acl" parameters applied to them so as to restrict users access to a predefined ACL or a CIDR.

   ```
   <param name="auth-calls" value="$${internal_auth_calls}"/>
   ```

   Value can be "false" to disable authentication on this profile, meaning that when calls come in the profile will *not* send an auth challenge to the caller.

please check more https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Sofia.conf.xml#auth-calls.

so now you can call your lua script on call and registration which actually check the registration,invite using custom logic.now freeswitch is not going to perform any authentication.

Comment: Dear Suren, thanks for your comment. It still requires me to pass the JWT to the FS inside custom-header. There seems to be no way around it.